# Connecting Arduino Uno to ESP8266

Tags: arduino, power-supply, wifi, esp8266

I want to connect my Arduino Uno to an ESP8266 without adding an external 3.3V power supply, so that I can have more I/O for switching LED's and relays.
Adding a capacitor will solve the problem?

Comment: No, a capacitor would not solve the problem. I am pretty positive that you will require a 5V to 3V3 voltage regulator at least.

Comment: ESPs use about 70ma, which might not leave enough room for other 3.3v devices. Use the UNO's 5v line, fed to an ams117@3.3 to power the esp w/o additional external supplies.

Comment: you mean adding an ams117@3.3 for the ESP only?

Comment: You didn't bother to mention HOW you are **connecting** anything. Which pins to which pins? Add a capacitor to what pins!?

Comment: I'm connecting the ESP to the arduino through SoftSerial (D2 and D3) and power it with 3.3v. The capacitor will be connect to vcc pin of the esp

Answer (score 2):

The Arduino Uno has a 3.3V linear regulator (LP2985) onboard. The 3.3V is available on the power connector. The problem is that such regulator only provides 150mA, which is not enough for the ESP8266 at full power.

A capacitor might be necessary, but it would solve the problem only if the ESP8266 has just few burst of high current usage, while spending most of its time at low current consumption.

Comment: The solution? :)

Comment: I don't want to add an external power supply for the ESP

Comment: Not even an LM1117-3.3 ?

Comment: you mean having a 3.3v regulator for ESP only?

Comment: yep. or use an external transistor and the 3.3V (as reference) to derive a "high current" 3.3V from the 5V pin.

Comment: note that i have two sensors connected to 3.3v

Comment: This is another problem. I assume their consumption is negligible, but the ESP might create too much noise. By the way, here you find that the power consumption i 170mA at the maximum power: http://espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/0a-esp8266ex_datasheet_en.pdf

Comment: @next-hack: those 170ma spikes last under 1ms, so a cap of over 1000uf would eliminate such spikes, and even a 330uf chops the spike's height in half.

Comment: if I use a coin battery just for the ESP?

Comment: Nope, a coin battery has a capacity that is very limited (About 200mAh for a CR2032). I.e. that would last for just one hour...
The LM1117 could be a better idea.. You just need to add it and 2 capacitors...

Answer (score 0):

The ESP8266's power consumption varies very much. When sending data to the WLAN, it has burst of 200 to 250 mA. Otherwise it uses more like 50 mA. So the power consumption depends on your usage pattern.

If you only send few data over WLAN, you can directly connect it to your Arduino if you use a beefy capacitor (1000uF or more) to cover peak consumption. Just try it. You can't damage anything.

Comment: "You can't damage anything." is not sound advice to someone who is new to a subject. Also that claim should be backed up. The 3.3V Arduino pin can source 150mA. You *might* be able to sink 250mA for very short bursts, however the 3.3V regulator's power comes from the 5V rail. So if the 5V rail is already maxed, then you have a different problem.